# Jsonata release version 1.8.5 issues with undefined objects

Tags: jsonata

It seems your latest release version 1.8.5, albeit a maintenance release, is forcing exceptions on undefined options. The group and map operators don't work on undefined objects any longer.

Can you let me know if this is intentional?
If so, can you let me know if any simple null checks have been implemented, rather using coalescing operator?

Thank you.

Comment: Please could you post an example using the 'save & share' button in the JSONata exerciser (try.jsonata.org)? Thanks.

Comment: https://try.jsonata.org/FdmYUen-a

Comment: This is an unintended regression.  Please could you raise an issue? https://github.com/jsonata-js/jsonata/issues/new